# Finding Islamic Date Using English Date Without any Library?

Tags: java, android, date-conversion, android-date

Here is mine code to convert Arabic/Islamic/Hijri Date to English/Georgian Date
Can anyone guide me how can i do inverse of it?

```
    public String ArabicToEnglish(String date){
        String [] sepratedString = ParseString(date);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(sepratedString[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(sepratedString[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(sepratedString[2]);

        double temp = (year-1)+(month-1)/12+(day-1)/354.3;
        temp*= 354.3/365.24;
        temp+=622.54;
        //find year
        year = (int) temp;
        temp = temp-year;
        //find month
        temp *= 12;
        double temp2 = temp;
        month = (int) temp;
        temp = temp - month;
        for(;;){
            if(temp2>temp2-month){
                month++;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        temp *= 30.4167;
        day = (int) temp;


        return String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month)+"-"+String.valueOf(year);
    }
```

I used this resource to get help : [Link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-convert-Hijri-dates-to-Gregorian-and-vice-versa-What-is-the-algorithm)

Comment: Without unit tests this code can't be trusted. This sort of stuff is notoriously tricky to get right. If you need to do the inverse, well, start trying.

Comment: Could you please specify?? Where to start trying? Would be thankful

Comment: Interesting challenge. What’s your objection to using a good and well-tested library?

Comment: Problem set limits me to do not use any library.

Comment: Here is a more robust accurate and safe method to convert any of the 5 Hijri Calendars to any of the 18 World Calendars without using external libraries or complex maths formulas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/function-to-convert-any-of-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world